# Core Plot custom labels show in the padding area when scrolling

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-plot

I have a simple line graph which allows the user to view a section of the graph area by scrolling. Everything works fine when the x and y axisConstraints were set and using default labeling policy.

After I set the CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone and use my custom labels, they show inside the padding area of the plot area frame when/after scrolling. How to make it like the default setting, where the labels are hidden in that area?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with Core Plot. See [issue 104](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=104).

Until this issue is fixed, you can use a plot space delegate to receive notifications when the graph scrolls. Check the new plot range and hide or remove labels that fall outside the range.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.
Not only the custom labels, the major ticks are also showed.
Hopes they will be fixed after version 0.9

Comment: This issue is fixed. See the issue link above for details about the fix.